# SparseArray - how to merge two arrays

Tags: android, performance

In my Android I'm using SparseArray to store values. How to merge two SparseArrays? There is no addAll or putAll method. Is only way to iterate through first array and put objects to second one? Is it efficient enough? Or should I just use HashMap instead?

Comment: addall() also iterate through the array

Comment: You can't really do much better than iterating through one and putting the elements individually in the other, even if a `putAll` method existed, since algorithmically it'd likely translate to pretty much the same thing given the container's requirements. Hash map might give you better performance or it might not, but the presence of a `putAll` doesn't necessarily mean the container can transfer elements any faster than linear time at best (unless it's a linked structure where it can just change one pointer). A presence of `putAll` might simply imply that the container can use its private...

Comment: ... data to more "efficiently" insert in bulk, but that's "efficiently" relative to single `puts` within the same container type, not efficiently in an absolute sense compared to other containers. For these kinds of things, it's best to just measure it if performance is a concern, but it's worth noting that linearly iterating through elements to transfer elements from one container to another is really quite normal as far as the required algorithmic complexity. You generally can't do any better except in the case of a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to merge two SparseArrays?

Iterate through first `SparseArray` and add the elements to second `SparseArray`.

> Is it efficient enough?

Even the `HashMap` also iterates through one of it's array for adding to the other. So definitely it will be efficient.